# Internet Backup if DSL & Cable Fail

Tags: internet, route, 3g, disaster

We have a T1, a DSL Line and a cable modem in each building to assure that we can connect to the internet in case one fails. However during the latest power outage we also lost all of them and were cut off from the world.

I purchased a few aircards and we managed to retrieve email and do bare necessities on the internet but all considered it was a less than favorable approach as aircards had to be shared and for some reasons I couldn't get it to work nicely alongside my network.

Now I wonder - Is there a router out there or some kind of device which has a 3G/4G connection which I could enable on my network so that employees at least can retrieve emails and purchase orders etc...?

I had a few people come up to me and say - "You really should have looked into an alternative route in case such a thing happens" - And I'm kind of stumped. Who could have known that all lines go down at the same time? But then again...

Comment: You have DSL, cable, and a T1 and they all failed a the same time?  Another method would be nice, but it seems pretty unlikely that they would all break at once.  There are 3G/4G ISPs [clearwire](http://www.clearwire.com/), so yes, you can get wireless connectivity in some places.  But they don't cover the whole world.  Basically your question becomes both too-localized and a shopping question which are off-topic here.

Comment: Maybe you want [Satellite Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_Internet_access#Two-way_satellite-only_communication)?

Comment: If three different access methods all went down at once, I'd try and figure out why instead of just adding a fourth method. That seems exceedingly unlikely without something weird happening.

Comment: It sounds like you need a UPS, not more routers and internet connections.

Comment: Satellite Internet doesn't work without a modem. (afaik) - Second, if someone heard what happened here on the east coast you will find that 10+ days without power, internet or phone was very common these past few weeks. (Winterstorm) We have a great generator (Manufacturing plant was able to continue working... 2600 gallons of gas a day to keep the generator going)

Comment: There are satellite internet, technologies that do work without a modem. (I linked to the section in the wikipedia article that covered that). The connectivity, certainly isn't great though, think high latency, very low speeds, and expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why searching for "3g wan router" doesn't give you the expected brands and models?

But this won't prevent you from Internet loss. Without electricity the GSM antennas of your provider may also be out of order.

Comment: Thank you. Don't know what I was thinking